# How to turn on load external Javascript on the Galaxy Nexus?

Tags: javascript, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-nexus

I just got my Galaxy Nexus and was browsing Stack Exchange (in both mobile and full theme) and got the following warning. As a result things like voting, the dropdown and such don't work. I never had this problem on Gingerbread, so I think it has something to do with Ice Cream Sandwich.

[image]

So I'd like to know which settings do I have to tweak so the Javascript gets loaded anyway?

It does seem to load on Dolphin, so it seems limited to the stock browser.

Comment: FYI: This does not reproduce in the emulator's stock browse (running ICS)

Comment: Maybe Stack Exchange is doing some weird stuff based on the client string and doesn't recognize the one from ICS?

Comment: That message means that jQuery fails to to load from http://ajax.googleapis.com

Comment: Can anyone else reproduce this on another Galaxy Nexus?

Comment: Does this happen on both wifi and mobile networks?

Comment: It happens on both @Mokubai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out my probably was solved by something as simple as clearing my cache.

Which makes me feel pretty stupid, because I should have done that before even bothering to ask. I never suspected this could happen straight out of the box, guess I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled JavaScript in `Settings -> Advanced -> Enable JavaScript`? The site works normally for me on ICS stock browser on my Galaxy S.

Comment: Yup its enabled, toggling it on or off doesn't really make a difference either